# How can I dynamically add a method to the Math class in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, introspection

I am trying to add the following method to the Math class in Ruby on Rails:

```
class Math
  def self.round_with_precision(number, precision)
    scalar = 10.0 ** precision
    number = number * scalar
    number = number.round
    number = number / scalar
    return number;
  end
end
```

I then added the following to my environment.rb:

```
require 'lib/math'
```

When I open up the Rails console I get the following error: './lib/math.rb:2:TypeError Math is not a class'

It seems like I'm overlooking something very simple.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Math is a module, just rename class to module.

Answer (score 2):

You can place the file containing this code in config/initializers and it will automatically be included. ~ Just a FYI.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `instance_eval`, you don't have to worry about whether to use `class` or `module`:

```
Math.instance_eval do
  def round_with_precision(number, precision)
    scalar = 10.0 ** precision
    (number * scalar).round / scalar
  end
end
```